# Changing StylisticSet for a specific character

Tags: unicode-math

I'm using the STIX2 fonts with LuaLaTeX and unicode-math. I'm trying the use StylisticSet 2, which changes the appearance of certain lowercase italic letters, but only on the letter z specifically. However this doesn't seem to be working for me, the command \mitz is redefined but the actual typed out character "z" remains the same:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[CharacterVariant=3]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range={\mitz},StylisticSet=2]
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}

\begin{document}
$z\mitz$
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image]

I would like the first "z" to look like the second. (Simply changing range to "z" produces an error, and using the codepoint "1D467 gives the same result.) Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `` `z `` to the `range` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}[CharacterVariant=3]
\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}[range={`z,\mitz},StylisticSet=2]
\setmainfont{STIXTwoText}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-Italic,
]

\begin{document}

$z\mitz\symit{z}\symbf{z}$

\end{document}
```

(On this machine I need to load this way the fonts.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

`unicode-math` gives `z` a `\Umathcode` that makes it typeset as U+1D467 *in the same font*.

The `range` option makes an *input* of character `"1D467` typeset as character U+1D467 *in the font with ss2 set*.

What you want is for `z` to act like an input of character `"1D467`, so give it the same `\Umathcode`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[CharacterVariant=3]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range={\mitz},StylisticSet=2]
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}

\begin{document}

\Umathcodenum`z=\Umathcodenum"1D467

$z\mitz$
\end{document}
```